# Core Data : 1 to many relation - no details saved

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, relationship, magicalrecord

I've got a relation in CoreData which supposedly should save details of the entity.

[image]

Basically I just followed recommendations for doing this in swift these days. But looks like no luck. At least my data should be there, but they are not in DB neither in the res variable. Parameter items:[RBPMyChargesDetailModel] is present on a call.

```
@NSManaged var year:NSNumber
@NSManaged var limit:NSNumber
@NSManaged var paidOther:NSNumber
@NSManaged var paidOverLimit:NSNumber
@NSManaged var paidRBP:NSNumber
@NSManaged var chargesDetails:NSMutableSet

class func create(year:NSNumber, limit:NSNumber, paidOther:NSNumber, paidOverLimit:NSNumber, paidRBP:NSNumber, items:[RBPMyChargesDetailModel]?)
{
    MagicalRecord.saveWithBlockAndWait({(localContext : NSManagedObjectContext!) in

        var res:RBPMyChargesModel = RBPMyChargesModel.createInContext(localContext) as! RBPMyChargesModel

            res.year = year
            res.limit = limit
            res.paidOther = paidOther
            res.paidOverLimit = paidOverLimit
            res.paidRBP = paidRBP

        if let it = items {
            res.chargesDetails.addObjectsFromArray(it)
        }

        NSLog("Details %@", res.chargesDetails)
    })
}
```

Help will be appreciated, since I am obviously doing something wrong.
BTW: I am using MagicalRecords to support my project.

Comment: "No luck" in what specific way, exactly?

Comment: I mean no records as chargesDetails have been save to DB, but data are present when I call the function.

Comment: do you have any validation on any of the properties? If a proper is required to not be nil, no data will be saved. The general code template looks ok, so I'm not sure what else it might be

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your model image, you got the to-many relationship the wrong way round. It should be

```
Model <----->> Detail
```

**not**

```
Model <<-----> Detail
```